# BigQuery ML Tensorflow model - UDF out of memory

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, google-bigquery

I'm trying to run a Tensorflow model in BigQuery. The model is a variant of BERT that is small enough to fit within BigQuery model limitations (<250MB).

I've tried to generate the predictions with the model using the following query directly from the BigQuery console:

```sql
SELECT
  input_1,
  input_2,
  prediction,
FROM
  ML.PREDICT(MODEL `MY_IMPORTED_MODEL`,
    (
    SELECT
      *,
    FROM
      `MY_DATA_TABLE`
    ))
```

However, the query resulted in the following error:

> Resources exceeded during query execution: UDF out of memory.

I have attempted to generate the predictions on a smaller sample from `MY_DATA_TABLE` with the following query:

```sql
SELECT
  input_1,
  input_2,
  prediction,
FROM
  ML.PREDICT(MODEL `MY_IMPORTED_MODEL`,
    (
    SELECT
      *,
    FROM
      `MY_DATA_TABLE`
    LIMIT 10
    ))
```

The smaller sample works perfectly fine.

I thought that maybe an `OVER` expression would fix the issue by forcing the usage of more slots, so I produced the following query (spoiler alert: failed with the out-of-memory error):

```sql
SELECT
  input_1,
  input_2,
  prediction,
FROM
  ML.PREDICT(MODEL `MY_IMPORTED_MODEL`,
    (
    SELECT
      *,
      FLOOR(CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY input_1) AS decimal) / 10) AS batch_number,
    FROM
      `MY_DATA_TABLE`
    ))
```

It seems that BigQuery attempts to feed too many rows at once to the model, resulting in a batch of the size that results in the out-of-memory error.

Since I cannot specify the `BATCH_SIZE` parameter while calling the `ML.PREDICT` function, I'd like to know if there's any other way of obtaining the predictions that wouldn't result in the out-of-memory errors.

There are 180 million rows to run the prediction for, so I'd like to do it from within the BigQuery (not the GCP AI Platform).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to split your model into multiple models and call a separate `ml.predict` for each of them.

The keras functional api makes this quite easy as you can compose different models and access them later with the `get_layer` method.